# What are the implications on the mechanics of connected particles over a pulley if the connecting string is not considered to be light?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

In high-school level mechanics, whenever we solve problems involving pulleys, we assume that the connecting string is light. But how would the mathematics be affected if the string is not considered light(but is considered inextensible)? I think our teacher said that the tension in the string on both sides wouldn't be equal (at least that's what I think I heard). But why is that? I've tried to see how this would work but I think my approach may not be correct. I just assumed that since the string now has a mass, we can simply shift the centres of gravity of the particles accordingly. Considering the acceleration of both particles to be equal (the string is inextensible), i concluded that the tensions must be equal. Although I think I might be wrong since I basically used the same mathematical framework as when the string is considered light. It would be helpful if anyone could tell me about the implications of a massive string with logic and mathematical proof.
One thing to note, I do not want the math for how the tension changes over time, just whether or not the tensions would be equal.

Answer (score 0):

A hanging string must supply tension to support whatever is below it. For a massless string, this is just whatever mass is attached to the end of the string. When the string has mass, we also must account for the weight of the string itself, but that weight that needs to be supported depends on how far along the string you are.

Imagine a heavy rope hanging from the ceiling - the very top of the rope has tension equal to the weight of the entire rope. Halfway down the rope only needs to support half the weight of the rope, and so has less tension. The very bottom bit of the rope doesn't need to support any weight at all, and actually has zero tension.

When a string has mass, you're effectively tying weights to a massless string at infinitesimal intervals, which results in varying tension along the length. A massless string allows you to ignore all this and assume that tension is equal everywhere, since tension is only caused by things at the *very end* of the string.

Answer (score 0):

To see this we don't really need the pulley, and the pulley just makes things more complicated.  So let's think about the simplest case we can: Two blocks connected by a ("heavy") string, sliding on a frictionless surface.  Something (say a person's hand) is pulling one block to the right.

[image]

The blocks have masses $m_A$, $m_B$, and the string has mass, $m_S$.  Because of the force by the hand, the whole thing (both blocks, and the string) are accelerating to the right.  Because of the string being inextensible (as you say) all three objects must have the same acceleration.  OK, so start with a free body diagram of each object.  There are vertical weight and normal forces on the blocks that are irrelevant, so I'm going to leave them out.

[image]

Hopefully my notation is clear?  For example, $\vec{F}_{SonA}$ is the force that the string exerts on block A.  This is what we would usually just call "tension" but here it will be more useful to think about all of the forces that we usually call tension and give them separate names, so we can see that they are not all the same size.  Newton's 3rd law tells us that the magnitudes of these forces obey

$F_{SonA} = F_{AonS}$

$F_{SonB} = F_{BonS}$

The equation of motion (a.k.a. Newton's 2nd law) for the string tells us that

$m_s a = F_{AonS} - F_{BonS}$

But since $m_s a$ is not zero, this tells us that $F_{AonS} > F_{BonS}$.  So, again by Newton's 3rd Law $F_{SonA} > F_{SonB}$.  In other words, "the tension exerted on A is bigger than the tension on B", as your teacher said.

Adding a pulley into this doesn't really change anything except changing some directions of the forces, and also allowing us to set this up without a force by a hand.